# Как проверить успешную регистрацию пользователя в плагине Woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

Есть страница регистрации и входа.
Нужно при успешной отправке формы регистрации отправлять событие в га. Но никак не могу разобраться где это можно сделать. Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Берете код события, страницу, куда редиректит woocommrece после регистрации, находите что-то типа "if isset()"(проверка на событие отправки формы) и вставляете свое событие туда. Без примеров кода больше нечем вам помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После успешной регистрации нового пользователя WooCommerce вызывает такой фильтр:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_auth_new_customer', true, $new_customer );
```

Попробуйте в своем фильтре вставить скрипт вызова события Google Analytics.

Ваш фильтр должен вернуть true.